# Move or copy .3gp files from one directory "External Dir" to another External directory in Android

Tags: android, file, audio, android-recyclerview, android-external-storage

I am checking some recorded audios and marking them. what I am trying to do is after when I mark audios and press submit button I want to move those audios " .3gp files" to another directory so that those audios do not appear next time when I open Recyclerview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research my colleague has found Apache IO library for file input/output stream. "https://github.com/apache/commons-io" this library helps in handling input/output file streams. other than that  we can also use FileUtils.copy(fileInputStream,FileOutputStream) but it required minimum API 29.